# Sonarqube grade build failed with "SonarQube server [http://x.12.11.18:9000] can not be reached"

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm experiencing a strange problem when running "gradlew sonarqube" with proxy. I have sonarqube server installed (using 2 minutes quick installation guide) on a remote server with IP: x.12.11.18.

When running the "gradlew sonarqube" on my local Mac, I got the error below.

./gradlew sonarqube
:app:sonarqube
SonarQube server [http://x.12.11.18:9000] can not be reached
:app:sonarqube FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

However, if I comment out systemProp.http.proxyPort settings in gradle.properties file, the "gradlew sonarqube" passed. Not exactly sure what's the problem? Your help would be highly appreciated!

gradle.properties

systemProp.http.proxyHost=gateway1.xxxx

**systemProp.http.proxyPort=8000** # If I comment out this line, the gradlew sonarqube would pass

systemProp.sonar.host.url=http://x.12.11.18:9000

---

### snippet of exception stacktrace

```
22:12:34.255 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':app:sonarqube' is up-to-date
22:12:34.256 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Executing task ':app:sonarqube' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
22:12:34.256 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':app:sonarqube'.
22:12:34.295 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] cache: /Users/mobile/.sonar/ws_cache/http%3A%2F%2Fx.66.12.18%3A9000/global
22:12:34.327 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] User cache: /Users/mobile/.sonar/cache
22:12:34.327 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Extract sonar-runner-batch in temp...
22:12:34.344 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Get bootstrap index...
22:12:34.344 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Download: http://x.66.12.18:9000/batch_bootstrap/index
22:13:34.575 [ERROR] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] SonarQube server [http://x.66.12.18:9000] can not be reached
22:13:34.578 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:sonarqube'
22:13:34.578 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:sonarqube FAILED
22:13:34.583 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:sonarqube (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 1 mins 0.339 secs.
22:13:34.583 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 1 mins 0.339 secs, idle: 0.0 secs
22:13:34.592 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
22:13:34.594 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
22:13:34.595 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
22:13:34.595 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
22:13:34.595 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:sonarqube'.
22:13:34.595 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unable to execute SonarQube
22:13:34.596 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
22:13:34.596 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
22:13:34.597 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:sonarqube'.
22:13:34.598 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
22:13:34.598 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
22:13:34.598 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
22:13:34.598 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
22:13:34.599 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
22:13:34.599 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
22:13:34.599 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
22:13:34.599 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
22:13:34.599 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
22:13:34.600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
22:13:34.600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
22:13:34.600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)
22:13:34.600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
22:13:34.600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
22:13:34.600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
22:13:34.601 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
22:13:34.601 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
22:13:34.601 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
22:13:34.601 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
22:13:34.601 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
22:13:34.601 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
22:13:34.601 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
22:13:34.602 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
22:13:34.602 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
22:13:34.602 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
22:13:34.602 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
22:13:34.602 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
22:13:34.602 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
22:13:34.603 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
22:13:34.603 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
22:13:34.603 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
22:13:34.603 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
22:13:34.603 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
22:13:34.604 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
22:13:34.604 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
22:13:34.604 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
22:13:34.604 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
22:13:34.604 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
22:13:34.605 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
22:13:34.605 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
22:13:34.605 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
22:13:34.606 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
22:13:34.606 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
22:13:34.606 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
22:13:34.607 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
22:13:34.607 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
22:13:34.607 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
22:13:34.607 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
22:13:34.608 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
22:13:34.608 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
22:13:34.608 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
22:13:34.609 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
22:13:34.609 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
22:13:34.609 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
22:13:34.609 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
22:13:34.609 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
22:13:34.610 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
22:13:34.610 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
22:13:34.612 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
22:13:34.612 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
22:13:34.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
22:13:34.620 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
22:13:34.620 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:100)
22:13:34.620 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:87)
22:13:34.621 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:87)
22:13:34.621 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:83)
22:13:34.621 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doStart(EmbeddedRunner.java:249)
22:13:34.622 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.start(EmbeddedRunner.java:187)
22:13:34.622 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.start(EmbeddedRunner.java:182)
22:13:34.622 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:83)
22:13:34.622 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
22:13:34.623 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
22:13:34.623 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
22:13:34.624 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
22:13:34.624 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
22:13:34.624 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
22:13:34.626 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
22:13:34.626 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
22:13:34.626 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 60 more
22:13:34.627 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
22:13:34.627 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:93)
22:13:34.627 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
22:13:34.627 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:40)
22:13:34.627 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:91)
22:13:34.627 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 75 more
22:13:34.628 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
22:13:34.628 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:207)
22:13:34.628 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:261)
22:13:34.629 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:215)
22:13:34.629 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
22:13:34.629 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
22:13:34.629 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
22:13:34.629 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
22:13:34.630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:79)
22:13:34.630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:909)
22:13:34.630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$300(HttpEngine.java:93)
22:13:34.631 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:894)
22:13:34.631 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:748)
22:13:34.631 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:277)
22:13:34.631 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:234)
22:13:34.631 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:196)
22:13:34.631 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
22:13:34.631 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:184)
22:13:34.632 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:121)
22:13:34.632 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.tryServerFirst(ServerConnection.java:148)
22:13:34.632 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.download(ServerConnection.java:112)
22:13:34.632 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:78)
22:13:34.632 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 78 more
22:13:34.632 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
22:13:34.632 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
22:13:34.633 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
22:13:34.633 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 96 more
22:13:34.633 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
22:13:34.633 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
22:13:34.633 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
22:13:34.633 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
22:13:34.634 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 1 mins 8.819 secs
22:13:34.643 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cp_settings class cache for settings file '/Users/mobile/Library/Application Support/Go Agent/pipelines/aegis-android-pr/feature2/settings.gradle' (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/2.8/scripts/settings_cxca5ys821jg8mocwphns8sid/cp_settings).
22:13:34.644 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on settings class cache for settings file '/Users/mobile/Library/Application Support/Go Agent/pipelines/aegis-android-pr/feature2/settings.gradle' (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/2.8/scripts/settings_cxca5ys821jg8mocwphns8sid/settings).
22:13:34.644 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cp_proj class cache for build file '/Users/mobile/Library/Application Support/Go Agent/pipelines/aegis-android-pr/feature2/build.gradle' (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/2.8/scripts/build_bh5kxa31ddennp2ltaxoqv8t9/cp_proj).
22:13:34.644 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on proj class cache for build file '/Users/mobile/Library/Application Support/Go Agent/pipelines/aegis-android-pr/feature2/build.gradle' (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/2.8/scripts/build_bh5kxa31ddennp2ltaxoqv8t9/proj).
22:13:34.645 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cp_proj class cache for build file '/Users/mobile/Library/Application Support/Go Agent/pipelines/aegis-android-pr/feature2/app/build.gradle' (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/2.8/scripts/build_22tm7r8h4l07b1mhzsi3thzrn/cp_proj).
22:13:34.645 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on proj class cache for build file '/Users/mobile/Library/Application Support/Go Agent/pipelines/aegis-android-pr/feature2/app/build.gradle' (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/2.8/scripts/build_22tm7r8h4l07b1mhzsi3thzrn/proj).
22:13:34.652 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache task history cache (/Users/mobile/Library/Application Support/Go Agent/pipelines/aegis-android-pr/feature2/.gradle/2.8/taskArtifacts) was closed 0 times.
22:13:34.653 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory] In-memory dependency metadata cache closed. Repos cached: 99, cache instances: 6, modules served from cache: 628, artifacts: 140
22:13:34.654 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.16/module-metadata.bin)
22:13:34.655 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache artifact-at-repository.bin (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.16/artifact-at-repository.bin)
22:13:34.655 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-artifacts.bin (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.16/module-artifacts.bin)
22:13:34.655 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/modules-2).
22:13:34.657 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolved configuration cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
22:13:34.658 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 16 (avg: 0.001 secs, total: 0.024 secs)
22:13:34.658 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.001 secs
22:13:34.658 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Plugin Resolution Cache (/Users/mobile/.gradle/caches/2.8/plugin-resolution) was closed 0 times.
22:13:34.659 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 compiler daemon(s).
22:13:34.659 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

Comment: can you please post your full exception stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Praveen. The exception stack trace is added to the above post. I am able to run "curl http://x.66.12.18:9000/batch_bootstrap/index" at command line after the build failure and get result like below.
sonar-batch-shaded-5.4.jar|6c1c10c526b82976353917245889c38f. Not sure why the build complains the server can't reached.

Comment: Facing same problem. Finally, remove proxy settings make it work. But it just a workaround!

Comment: It's really weird. Removing proxy port setting does fix "gradlew sonarqube" build, but my "gradlew build" would fail since it needs to download other dependencies through the proxy. Are there any other workaround?

Comment: I have no idea. I'am using Maven plugin and already specify `nonProxyHosts` for Sonar server in Maven config. But it does not work. I think that may be a problem with their plugin!

Comment: You can try `systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts` in `gradle.properties`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Thanks for the help. This workaround works! :)

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

I am gettin gthis error while running gradlew sonarqube.

Answer (score 0):

You should bypass proxy for your Sonar address. In `gradle.properties`:

```
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=x.12.11.18
```